# Automatically updating the header and footer based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a SharePoint site that manages documents.  The document have custom document property. I would like to insert some of those document property into my header and footer. I have been able find away to show the values in cells.  But not update automatically to the header and footer.

Does anybody know how to automatically update the header and footer based which contains cell ref. to the document properties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have solve my issue.

Comment: Do you mean that you have **solved** your issue or that you have **to** solve your issue, @Brooke?

Comment: Please delete your question if you don't intend to post an answer addressing the solution you found.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use content type for that. For more information visit this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms472236(v=office.14).aspx
Pay special attention to section that specifies "DocumentTemplate Element".
If you need more detailed help, you should post a more detailed question that contains what you have done so far, where you failed and what you want to do - specifically.